# ingresar dos cadenas y que me retorne una

Tags: python-3.x

Hola debo inresar dos strings en python ejemplo:
s1 = Hola
s2 = Chao
y el resultado debe ser:
l 
deben eliminarse los elementos reptidos

```
def cadena():
    s1 = input("Cadena 1: ")
    s2 = input("Cadena 2: ")
    i=0
    a=len(s2)
    while i<a:
       b=s1.replace(s2[i],"")
       i=i+1
    print(b)       
def main():
    cadena()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

ese codigo tengo ayudenme por favor

Comment: el output puede que lo tengas mal escrito y sea "LC" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que tu output en vez de ser "Hl" es "LC" ya que "H" no sería un elemento duplicado porque existe en ambas palabras. Una posible y humilde solución podría ser devolver las letras de cada palabra que no esten en la otra. Eso mismo lo podemos pasar a código de la siguiente manera:

```
palabra = 'hola'
palabra2 = 'chao'

for letra in palabra:
    if letra not in palabra2:
        print(letra)
```

output:

```
l
```

Ahora partiendo de ese ejemplo, podemos construir la función `cadena()`, para que nos devuelva todo el conjunto. con ayuda del método `upper()` de las cadenas, lo convertimos en mayúsculas, de esta manera nos ahorramos el problema de que el usuario ingrese "HoLa" o "holA". Y luego hacemos uso de dos [comprensiones de listas](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) para devolver las letras de cada palabra a analizar.

```
def cadena():
    s1 = input("Cadena 1: ").upper()
    s2 = input("Cadena 2: ").upper()

    return [i for i in s1 if i not in s2] + [i for i in s2 if i not in s1]
```